¿Cómo incrementar variables php dentro de un script js?
Buen día, tengo un proyecto donde en una función PHP obtengo datos de una bd MySQL que se guardan en un array, el cual se retorna.
En el documento HTML tengo un script PHP donde obtengo ese array y lo almaceno en una variable. Posteriormente, fuera de PHP, introduzco un script JavaScript donde, por medio de un ciclo for, intento dar valor a unos input text con los valores que tiene el array PHP, y es aquí donde estoy atorada, pues el iterador PHP ($j) se queda en 0, por ende, en todos mis input text aparece el mismo valor.
Ciertamente soy inexperta en esto de combinar JS y PHP; espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.
Adjunto los códigos:
<?php
function traer($np, $ne, $cr){
    require('conexionbd.php');
    $us = $_SESSION['Usuario'];
    $array = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < $cr; $i++){
        $nax = "p".$np."e".$ne."txt".($i+1);
        $comando = "SELECT $nax from progresion$np WHERE nusuario = '$us'";
        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $comando);
        if($row = $consulta->fetch_assoc()){
            $array[$i] = $row[$nax];
            
        } 
        
        
    }
    return $array;
}

<?php 
            include("traer.php");  
            $htarray= traer(9, 1, 11);
$j = 0;
            ?>
            <script>
                
                    for(var i = 0; i<11; i++){
                        
                        let aux = "p9e1txt"+(1+i).toString();
                        let actual = <?php echo $htarray[$j];?>;
                        document.getElementById(aux).value = actual;
                        
                    }
                    <?php $j +=1; ?>
                    
                </script>


Podrías intentar hacer el for en php, y dentro ejecutas los scripts js

Intenté esto pero parece no funcionar, desconozco si hay un error :(  <?php             include ("traer.php");             $htarray = traer(9, 1, 11);             //echo $htarray[0] . " " . $htarray[1];             for ($j = 0; $j < 11; $j++) {                 echo '<script>let aux = "p9e1txt"' . ($j + 1);                 echo 'let actual =' . $htarray[$j];                 echo 'document.getElementById(aux).value = actual;</script>';             }             ?>

recuerda revisar la consola del navegador, eso te mencionará si hay un error en el script de js, te dejaré una posible solución en las respuestas

$j = 0; pone $j a cero, <?php echo $htarray[$j];?> imprime el primer ( index 0 ) elemento del array, <?php $j +=1; ?> incrementa $j, finaliza el script php y retorna el html : script javascript  con los valores fijos ( let actual es siempre el mismo valor )

Lo primero que debes tener claro es que

PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor, al momento de procesar la petición, por ejemplo que el usuario haya navegado a la URL de tu script PHP.  Toda la salida que produce PHP, es enviada al navegador, que es el cliente, y PHP termina su trabajo hasta que se realice una nueva petición al servidor, ya sea explícitamente por el usuario, o una típica llamada AJAX desde JavaScript.
En un script de PHP no tienes acceso a la memoria de la máquina cliente, por ejemplo, dónde está el navegador, y por tanto, no puedes acceder a ningún artefacto que esté en ella, como variables de JavaScript o el DOM.

JavaScript, junto a HTML y CSS, son interpretados del lado del cliente. No tienen acceso a los recursos del servidor, por ejemplo a las variables que en su momento existieron dentro del script de PHP que pudo haberles dado vida. Mediante JavaScript puedes realizar nuevas peticiones que hagan que se ejecuten scripts en el servidor, pero aún así no tienes acceso a la memoria de esa máquina.


Una vez tengas esto claro, puedes encontrar maneras de lograr lo que quieres. Por ejemplo, para el caso que describes, yo veo dos posibles soluciones:
Generar HTML ya listo para consumir desde PHP
La primera, es que realices la llamada a traer() y, en base a sus resultados, generes directamente el HTML de los elementos, de esa manera no tienes que iterar por ellos del lado del cliente, pues este ya recibe el HTML final, con los valores obtenidos desde la DB integrados.
Mira este ejemplo sencillo con un arreglo constante:
<?php
$colores = array("rojo", "verde", "azul", "amarillo");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($colores); $i++) {
  $color = $colores[$i];
  $nombre = "p9e1txt".$i;
  echo("<input name='$nombre' id='$nombre' value='$color'><br>\n");
}
?>

playgrond
Esto produce como salida:


<input name='p9e1txt0' id='p9e1txt0' value='rojo'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt1' id='p9e1txt1' value='verde'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt2' id='p9e1txt2' value='azul'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt3' id='p9e1txt3' value='amarillo'><br>



Como puedes ver, el navegador recibe directamente el código HTML ya con sus valores, por lo que no hay magia de ese lado.
Generar el arreglo de datos para ser procesado en JavaScript
En este otro enfoque, lo que haces en PHP es construir un arreglo válido para JavaScript y luego escribes el código para realizar el proceso enteramente en javascript.
Por ejemplo, este código:
<?php
  $colores = array("rojo", "verde", "azul", "amarillo");
?>
<input name='p9e1txt0' id='p9e1txt0'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt1' id='p9e1txt1'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt2' id='p9e1txt2'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt3' id='p9e1txt3'><br>
<script>
  const colores = [
    <? foreach($colores as $color) {
        echo('"'.$color.'",');
    } ?>
  ];
  for(var i=0; i<colores.length; i++){
    let aux = "p9e1txt"+(i).toString();
    let actual = colores[i];
    document.getElementById(aux).value = actual;
  }
</script>

playground
Genera esta salida:


<input name='p9e1txt0' id='p9e1txt0'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt1' id='p9e1txt1'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt2' id='p9e1txt2'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt3' id='p9e1txt3'><br>
<script>
  const colores = [
    "rojo","verde","azul","amarillo",  ];
  for(var i=0; i<colores.length; i++){
    let aux = "p9e1txt"+(i).toString();
    let actual = colores[i];
    document.getElementById(aux).value = actual;
  }
</script>



Que, como puedes ver, finalmente llena los datos en cada uno de los <input>'s de la página.
Generar JavaScript sin pasar el arreglo de datos
Puedes tener el HTML estático y generar líneas de JavaScript para ir asignando los valores uno a uno a los input's, sin pasar el arreglo de datos.
Este script:
<?php
  $colores = array("rojo", "verde", "azul", "amarillo");
  $i=0;
?>
<input name='p9e1txt0' id='p9e1txt0'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt1' id='p9e1txt1'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt2' id='p9e1txt2'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt3' id='p9e1txt3'><br>
<script>
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<count($colores); $i++) {
    $aux = "p9e1txt".$i;
    $color = $colores[$i];
    echo("  document.getElementById('$aux').value = '$color';\n");
} 
?>
</script>

playground
Genera este código:


<input name='p9e1txt0' id='p9e1txt0'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt1' id='p9e1txt1'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt2' id='p9e1txt2'><br>
<input name='p9e1txt3' id='p9e1txt3'><br>
<script>
  document.getElementById('p9e1txt0').value = 'rojo';
  document.getElementById('p9e1txt1').value = 'verde';
  document.getElementById('p9e1txt2').value = 'azul';
  document.getElementById('p9e1txt3').value = 'amarillo';
</script>



Como puedes ver, ahora el script contiene tantas líneas como hay en el arreglo de PHP y se van a ejecutar al cargar la página, por lo que se asignan nuevamente los valores.
Otras formas
Hay quizás docenas de otras formas de hacerlo, a cada programador se le debiera ocurrir la propia, y con conocimientos más avanzados puedes pasar a llamadas AJAX, hoy por hoy Fetch y, con seguridad, muchas otras más.
La idea de la respuesta es que vayas aclarando tus ideas y tengas algunos ejemplos de los que puedas tirar para, una vez que entiendas mejor, producir tu propia solución.

implode para array simples y json_encode en general van bien para armar cosa que luego consume javascript inline o ajax

Lo sé. Estoy manteniendo la respuesta simple, pues la AP parece estar dando sus primeros pasos. La idea no es que la respuesta dé código listo para producción hoy en día, sino ayudarla a absorber los conceptos básicos.

Realizando lo siguiente puede darte la solución pero generará múltiples scripts según la cantidad de loops
<?php include "traer.php";
$htarray = traer(9, 1, 11);
for ($j = 0; $j < 11; $j++) {
    ?>
    <script>
        let aux = "p9e1txt"+(1+<?php echo $j;?>).toString();
        let actual = '<?php echo $htarray[$j];?>';
        document.getElementById(aux).value = actual;
    </script>
    <?php
} 
?>

